# XQuery concat not outputting document XML in expected way

Tags: xquery, marklogic

```
let $d := doc('foo.xml')

return concat('let $d := &#xD;&#xD;', $d)
```

returns

```
let $d :=

bar
```

I need it to return:

```
let $d :=

<foo>bar</foo>
```

Comment: mblakele already 'warned' you enough about the possible dangers of generating code, that you intend to eval, or otherwise execute without intermediate control. I'm curious though about the bigger picture. We might be able to suggest alternative routes which would prevent using risky methods..

Comment: This was a piece of throwaway code for generating some xquery to load some data. I am however interested in mitigating XQuery injection. At the moment I am using "Query objects" that encapsulate xquery and use straightforward string replacement for variables. Is there a better way? (I'm sure there is - perhaps a library to support the safe replacement of values in the query?)

Comment: Well, you can prevent quite a lot of issue if you make sure the injected values only represent strings, and don't allow premature closing of those strings, by escaping special chars, inserting things in XML first, or else. There are some vendor-specific extensions that may help as well. Most XQuery parsers, inclusing that of MarkLogic, allow using eval type functions, which typically also allow parameter replacement. Next to this, MarkLogic also supports xdmp:value, a light-weight eval, and also xdmp:unpath, to resolve variables holding XPath-path-like expressions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Reading the function signature for `fn:concat`, there is no reason to expect it to output XML. From http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-concat

```
fn:concat(
  $arg1 as xs:anyAtomicType?,
  $arg2 as xs:anyAtomicType?,
  ...)
as xs:string
```

That is, it takes a variable number of atomic items and returns a string. So if you pass it an XML node, it will attempt to atomize that and return a string result. If you haven't run into atomization yet, try `string(doc($uri))` to see what happens.

Ignoring that, it looks like you're trying to build an XQuery expression using string manipulation - perhaps for use with `xdmp:eval`? That's fine, but don't pass in the XML using `xdmp:quote`. For correctness, performance, and security reasons, the right tool for this job is an external variable.

```
xdmp:eval('
  declare variable $INPUT external ;
  let $d := $INPUT
  return xdmp:describe($d)',
  (xs:QName('INPUT'), $d))
```

Better yet, write the string part as a separate XQuery module and `xdmp:invoke` it with the same external variable parameters.

Why do it this way? Correctness, efficiency and security. If you get into the habit of blindly evaluating strings, you are setting yourself up for problems. Passing a node reference is more efficient than quoting a large node. When you quote XML as a string you may end up with XQuery-significant characters, such as `{`. Then you have to escape them (or switch to using `xdmp:unquote`, but that makes it even less efficient). Any escaping will be error-prone. In SQL the classic way to handle this is with a bind variable, and with XQuery it is an external variable. As with bind variables in SQL, external variables handle escaping. This also makes injection attacks much more difficult.

Answer (score 0):

Use pipes to concatenate.
Eg: $a||$b
If your variables are of atomic type, then you can use a string-join.
eg:, $a||fn:string-join(($b),",")

Answer (score -2):

```
let $d := xdmp:quote(doc('foo.xml'))

return concat('let $d := &#xD;&#xD;', $d)
```

Comment: seems a little unfair to answer your own question :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer says "Stack Exchange has always explicitly encouraged users to answer their own questions." This may not be the best answer, though.

Comment: If you plan to `xdmp:eval` the result of that `concat`, and it contains any curly braces or other XQuery syntax, it may throw an error or do unexpected things. If an attacker can control that XML, that becomes an injection attack. It could result in data theft or destruction. Consider what happens if `foo.xml` contains `<test>{xdmp:restart(xdmp:hosts(), 'ha!ha!')}</test>` for example.

Comment: I didn't know about that self-answer post! Pretty interesting.